# Showing this set is not path connected

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

Show that the region $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x< 0 \ \text{or} \ x>1 \}$ is not path connected.

Suppose that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x< 0 \ \text{or} \ x>1 \}$ is path connected. Then we can define a path $L$ from $(a,y)$ to $(b,y)$, where $a < 0$, $b >1$ and $y$ is arbitrary in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $$L = \{(a,b) : (1-t)a+tb, t \in [0,1] \}.$$

My issue is that I've taken a particular path, the result is obvious, but I'm unsure of how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: As the second coordinate, $y$ is in $\mathbb{R},$ not in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Note all you need is one *specific* pair of points and a contradiction from assuming a continuous path between them.

Comment: Indeed a particular path proves nothing. Instead, consider the points $a=(2,0)$ and $b=(-1,0)$, and a continuous path from $a$ to $b$, and show there is a point on the path not in the domain.

Comment: Yes, as Did notes getting one path not to work is not enough. What I meant in the remark is that one can choose the two endpoints specifically, but after that one has to show no continuous path between them (staying in the space).

Comment: Might be easiest to prove that it is just disconnected

Answer (score 2):

The projection $\pi$ on the $x$-axis is a continuous map, hence assuming that there is a path $\gamma$ between $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$, there is an interval (given by $\pi(\gamma)$) enclosing $-2$ and $2$ in $\pi(X)$. However, $-2$ and $2$ belong to two different connected components of $\pi(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.